# Hyperlink Caching with Old content

Tags: php, caching, hyperlink

I have a hyper link in a button
https://example/video.php?v='+Math.random());

This link leads to a php file with a live IP cam feed. The issue im facing is that the browser caches the old video and does not search for a new one from the server. When i do a hard refresh or clear cache in browser settings it works fine.

What i have tried

1. I have added a Math.random() in the link so that the browser looks for a new file. I even use a Get parameter inside the php file to show the video. Even though the version number is different on each request , still th old content comes.
2. I have added no cache parameters

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

And i tried many other headers as well, but of no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Explain what _"This link leads to a php file with a live IP cam feed"_ actually means.

Comment: Hey its a php file with a  video tag. And that video tag has a src of a video stored in the server. Thanks!

Comment: Both your attempts are affecting only your PHP script. If you want the browser to reload the video file itself without taking it from cache, then you would either need to respond with those headers for the video file itself, or append a cache buster parameter to its URL that you give as the src for the video element.